# ng2-pdf-viewer show blurry text when display a number of PDFs in a grid

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, electron

I am building an electron app that runs an angular app that shows a number of PDFs in a grid, how many PDFs that app can display in a grid.

The thing that displaying 6 PDFs or more causes some of the smaller text to appear blurry.  To add context our customer wishes to have 9 or more PDFs in a grid.

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer 7.0.0 to display the PDFs.

Angular 11.2.8
Electron 12.0.6

Here is snippet of my HTML in the angular component

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="pdf-grid-mat" *ngIf="pdfs.length > 0">
    <mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" rowHeight="fit" style="height:100vh">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let pdf of pdfs">
        <pdf-viewer [src]="pdf.url" [rotation]="0" [original-size]="true" [autoresize]="true" [show-all]="false"
          [fit-to-page]="true" [zoom-scale]="'page-fit'" [render-text]="false" [render-text-mode]="0" [external-link-target]="'blank'"
          class="pdf-Viewer" [show-borders]="true"></pdf-viewer>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is my belief that PDFs are vector based and should be nice and sharp whatever the resolution and scale.